# How to declare a var of type delegate RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I can't find the syntax for declaring a property for my user control of type delegate RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler (like slider ValueChange handler)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589771.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create an event:

```
public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler MyEvent;
```

However, in order for it to work correctly, you need to create a [routed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyButtonSimple));

// Provide CLR accessors for the event
public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
{
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); } 
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
}
```